# Add support for /qid/uid/slug questions

Tags: feature-request

I just stumbled upon another "shared link" that I had to actually quick to find out where it points to because information about it was neither in the URL nor in the hyperlink caption. Could we have share links contain the summary of the question title and update all links within stackexchange.com to those?

## Edit:

Since not everyone understood what I propose, here's an example.

This is how currently a link to this question works:

`https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/268322/add-support-for-qid-uid-slug-questions`

And if I was to create a share link, it would look like this:

`https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/268322/201072`

The problem is that I can create a [link like this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/268322/add-support-for-qid-uid-slug-questions) and [like this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/268322/201072). And in the second case, you cannot guess where the link refers to without clicking it, while on the first you can just hover your mouse over it and see the URL at the bottom, which contains the question title (`https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/268322/**add-support-for-qid-uid-slug-questions**`). My suggestion is to change the share links scheme to make them contain the question title as in the regular links.

## Why is it helpful?

In my opinion the titles in the question URLs are a convenient way to find out where the question points to without actually clicking it. Not adding it for shared links is an inconvenience and the problem is that there's an incentive towards creating share links, which create a mess.

Comment: Do you mean the "share links" that Stack Exchange generates?

Comment: Yup. Could you edit my post so that it's clearer if you have an idea how you could improve it?

Comment: You list a feature request but no information about how users would benefit if this were implemented; just that you want it.  What is the justification for this feature request?  How would users benefit?  Can you give an example use case?  Is the benefit more than "de minimus"?  Why is it important to have human-readable URLs?

Comment: Because it carries information about what the answer title is, which is a usability improvement. The slugs were added to the normal question links for this reason and I would say that the same applies to share links.

Comment: This is your question so please [edit] it to provide requested clarifications rather than creating a comment trail that potential answerers may or may not read.

Answer (score 4):

The *point* of the "share" links is to be short, so that you can e.g. tweet them easily.  Adding the slug to those links would pretty much defeat their main purpose.

Yes, it's sometimes annoying to have a short link that gives no indication of what it's about before you open it.  At least with SE "share" links, you know that you'll end up at an SE question / answer, and not, say, at some random shock or malware site that a generic URL shortener might send you to.